# Term describing behaviour of someone that likes to talk about shame or disgust of people, institutions or other things

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

The closest description I can think of is a "drama queen/king", except that tends to describe people who like being *in* a drama.

Instead, I want a phrase describing people who like to pick up on stories such as the following:

- questionable decisions of others
- controversies
- immoral acts

and then they get on their soapbox and passionately rant, uttering phrases like "it's disgusting", "it's a joke", "anyone who agrees with them should be ashamed".

Perhaps the descriptive term for that person might need to include that they are often immune to reason on subjective topics, and that the rants cause displeasure in the listeners, since frequent rants can wear listeners down, as the tone is loud, highly opinionated and of a very negative nature.

The reason I ask is I want search terms to Google to find techniques for dealing with such a person, and protecting one's self from their effects.

Edit: it is not really about whether someone finds faults in others, but the manner in which they frequently rant about issues, either in others, or institutions, or the nature of things.

Comment: Your query brings a number of expressions to mind.  A person such as you describe can certainly be labeled, _judgmental_.  _Negative_ and _control freak_ also present themselves as applicable.  _Mrs. Grundy_, a character from a play by Thomas Merton, has long been evoked as the personification of stiflingly conventional morality.  A person who is obsessed with identifying and pillorying wrongdoers could be labeled, metaphorically,  _a vigilante_.  I'm not sure that your issue sits comfortably in an English language forum, but best of luck in exorcising the evil spirits, whatever you call them.

Comment: ... Yes, 'judgmental' is the answer.

Comment: A secular bible-thumper.

Comment: Depending on how general the person's feelings of disgust toward other people are, you might consider **misanthropic**, which Merriam-Webster defines as "marked by a hatred or contempt for humankind."

Comment: There's some pretty judgmental down-voting going on with the answers here !!

Comment: As described in the OP the words that spring to mind are - *pain (in the neck)* and *bore*.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

a **"moralist"** or a **"pseudo-moralist"** depending on how that person really feels about the object of their criticism.  A moralist is someone who has very strong opinions about what is right and what is wrong.  A pseudo-moralist tries to sound like a moralist but doesn't really share the same convictions.

> - [**moralist**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/moralist) - (noun) -  **"a person who seeks to regulate the morals of others or to imbue others with a sense of morality"**

**a moralistic gossip(er)** may be morespecific.

Answer (score -1):

Consider ***[moralizer](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/moralizer)***, from the verb ***[moralize](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/moralizer)***, which means

> to reflect on or express opinions about something in terms of right and wrong, especially in a self-righteous or tiresome way.

A moralizer would thus be a self-righteous or tiresome person who expresses opinions about something in terms of right and wrong.

There are doubtless other words for your concept.

Answer (score -1):

> The reason I ask is I want search terms for Google, to find techniques for dealing with such a person, and protecting oneself from their effects.

*Troll*

*Internet troll*

*Hatemonger*

These three options will get you far in your search.

Answer (score -2):

For the characteristic of people who enjoy *[...] shame or disgust of others' behaviours* consider Schadenfreude.

I realise this doesn't encompass the *talking about others* aspect of the question.

> **Schadenfreude**
>   : a feeling of enjoyment that comes from seeing or hearing about the troubles of other people
>   — [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/schadenfreude)

Comment: any advice why this was down voted?